# Sub query of aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server

Can Anyone correct this query please?
I just don't know how to make it work.

```
 SELECT ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark,Max(SumOFMarks),Min(SumOFMarks)
FROM
(
SELECT    ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark,sum(StudentMark)SumOFMarks 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID 
INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
WHERE ClassCourses.ClassID=1
group by ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark               
)AS T
```

Comment: In future, it really helps if you also post the table definitions and the error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT T.ClassID,
    T.CourseID,
    T.MaxMark,
    Max(SumOFMarks),
    Min(SumOFMarks)
FROM
(
    SELECT    ClassCourses.ClassID,
        ClassCourses.CourseID,
        ClassCourses.MaxMark,
        sum(StudentMark) SumOFMarks 
    FROM Users 
    INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID 
    INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
    INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
    WHERE ClassCourses.ClassID=1
    group by ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark               
)AS T
GROUP BY T.ClassID,
     T.CourseID,
     T.MaxMark
```

The outer SELECT statement is missing the `GROUP BY` clause - I've added it.  Look at the last 3 lines.

Comment: ClassCourses is the alias of the inner query's table.

Answer (score 3):

Even After Corrections of Aliasing & Group By on outer query, FYI Max(T.SumOfMarks) and Min(T.SumOfMarks) will produce the same value.

Comment: You are correct.  Perhaps an example of how to solve that problem might get your answer accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Just `GROUP BY` at the end and fix table aliases :

```
SELECT T.ClassID, 
       T.CourseID, 
       T.MaxMark, 
       MAX(T.SumOFMarks),
       MIN(T.SumOFMarks)
FROM
(
SELECT ClassCourses.ClassID,
       ClassCourses.CourseID,
       ClassCourses.MaxMark,
       SUM(StudentMark) SumOFMarks 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID 
INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
WHERE ClassCourses.ClassID = 1
GROUP BY ClassCourses.ClassID,
         ClassCourses.CourseID,
         ClassCourses.MaxMark               
)AS T
GROUP BY ClassID,CourseID,MaxMark
```

Answer (score 0):

Your alias was wrong in the Outer query. I removed ClassCourses and added T instead.

```
SELECT T.ClassID,T.CourseID,T.MaxMark,Max(T.SumOFMarks),Min(T.SumOFMarks)
FROM
(
SELECT     
ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark,sum(StudentMark)SumOFMarks 
FROM Users 
 INNER JOIN 
     UserExams
  ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID 
 INNER JOIN Exams 
  ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
 INNER JOIN ClassCourses 
  ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID 
  AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
WHERE ClassCourses.ClassID=1
group by ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark               
)AS T
GROUP BY T.ClassID,T.CourseID,T.MaxMark;
```

Comment: Miss the final GROUP BY.

Comment: added the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE like that :

```
WITH CteUsers (ClassID, CourseID, MaxMark, SumOFMarks)
AS (
    SELECT ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark,sum(StudentMark)SumOFMarks 
    FROM Users 
    INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID 
    INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
    INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
    WHERE ClassCourses.ClassID=1
    group by ClassCourses.ClassID,ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MaxMark               
)
SELECT ClassID,CourseID,MaxMark,Max(SumOFMarks),Min(SumOFMarks)
FROM CteUsers
GROUP BY ClassID,CourseID,MaxMark
```